# Disallow [free-software] and guide users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, disallow-tag

The tag [free-software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-software) keeps [being re-created](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/what-to-do-with-the-free-software-tag), but in practice it is ambiguous, which is why [we don't use it](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17/tags-for-free-software-and-free-software?s=2%7C1.0303). I just went and retagged the 5 questions that had it — 2 clearly meaning FOSS, 2 clearly meaning “I don't want to pay money” and one probably meaning “I don't want to pay money”. The spread illustrates the ambiguity.

Please disallow [free-software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-software) and give it [the same guidance as `free`](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/927/guide-users-who-try-to-use-the-tag-free).

By the way, `free` used to be disallowed, but for some reason it no longer is. Please disallow it again.

Comment: I agree [thus free-software must die](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/12851?m=13876193#13876193) :)

Answer (score 4):

Shog9 has added `free` and `alternative` back to the list of disallowed tags and also added `free-software`. `free` and `free-software` guide the user towards [gratis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gratis) and [open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source).

It turns out that disallowed tag entries are culled automatically if they aren't triggered for 90 days. Our experience shows that this isn't ideal: our undesirable tags came back. Maybe disallowed tags that have explicit guidance should not expire?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would ever be useful to automatically expire a disallowed entry. Why does this happen?